# Mapping a ternary association with FluentNHibernate, using IDictionary<TKey,TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map a ternary association using FluentNhibernate.

I have 3 tables:

- `TUser(PK int id, string name, ...)`
- `TGroup(PK int id, string name, ...)`
- `TRole(PK int id, string name, ...)`

And a 4th one that associates them, representing the ternary association:

- `TUserGroupRole(FK int userid, FK int groupid, FK int roleid)`

Basically, a user has a particular role for a group. I'm using 3 types in my model :

- `User`
- `UserGroup`
- `UserRole`

In the `User` class, I want to use an `IDictionary<UserGroup,UserRole>` to index user roles by groups:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<UserGroup, UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Using regular hbm fashioned XML mapping file, I achieved that with a `<map>` element, like so (pseudo mapping):

```
<map name="Roles" table="TUserGroupRole">
    <key column="userid"/>
    <index-many-to-many column="groupid" class="UserGroup"/>
    <many-to-many column="roleid" class="UserRole"/>
</map>
```

**I wasn't able to figure out how to generate the same mapping using FluentNhibernate**, so any help on this point would be very appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted on http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/085935da193cf2d7

Answer (score 1):

In response to the reply you got on the FNH group, make sure you are exporting your mapping files like:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyObject>()
    .ExportTo("path")
```

I tend to agree with that response because I have only ever seen that type of exception when elements are out of order; that is when the key/index or id element is not the first child.

Answer (score 0):

with FNH 1.3 it should look like

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
    .ParentKeyColumn("userid")
    .AsTernaryAssociation("groupid")
    .ChildKeyColumn("roleid");
```